# Script to add users to mariadb

Tags: database, bash, scripting, mariadb

I am trying to add users into mariadb. Male users use an airline as password and females use a continent as a password all this info is taken form a csv file.

For some reason my script is not working. here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

FILENAME=mgarr048.csv  

while IFS=: read -r username first last gender dob state municipality season continent elective f1 airline
do
    (( gender == "m" )) || continue
    mysql -e GRANT INSERT ON *.* to $username@'%' IDENTIFIED by $airline;
done
```

csv headers

```
username,first,last,gender,dob,state,municipality,season,continent,elective,f1,airline
```

Comment: Saying that's just "Not working" does not provide enough details

Comment: What happens is that it acts like its running but, stays like that forever  and if i hit enter it shows the usage for adding users into the db

Comment: add `set -x` to help debug

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your script you tell it to read FILENAME.  Modify your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME="mgarr048.csv"

while IFS=, read -r username first last gender dob state municipality season continent elective f1 airline
do
    if [[ "$gender" != "m" ]]
    then
        echo "mysql -e GRANT INSERT ON *.* to $username@'%' IDENTIFIED by "$airline""
    fi
done < "$FILENAME"
```

- You said you have a CSV file, so I changed `IFS=;` to `IFS=,`.  C in CSV is "comma".
- You can read a full description on bash loops to read files here: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

**EDIT**

Since I do not have your database to test, I added `echo` to the `mysql` line.  Remove it to use this on your system.  If you get a `mysql` error, it is not the script, it is related to your `mysql` command and/or database.

Tested with that data set:

```
username1,user1,name1,m,1111-11-11,State1,City1,season1,continent1,elective1,f1,airline1
username2,user2,name2,f,2222-22-22,State2,City2,season2,continent2,elective2,f2,airline2
```

Output:

```
mysql -e GRANT INSERT ON *.* to username2@'%' IDENTIFIED by airline2
```

Comment: It does not work, this is the output :                                                                              Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
abort-source-on-error             FALSE
auto-rehash                       TRUE
auto-vertical-output              FALSE.....

Comment: See the edited version.